# make a variable available to all fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I'm making a quiz app, there is main activity and it contains fragments which are questions like (Radio Button, Checkbox, Drag and drop questions) . How to collect the Score from all the fragments.

Comment: while submitting the answer you need to submit to the activity holding that fragment. or you can use shared fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that.

1. You can add Set/Get method in Your activity and fetch that from
   fragment when you need them.
2. Create `static` variable in Activity class and you can access with 'ActivityClassName'.
3. Use Shared Preference and get access of that data anywhere. You can reset when you need and update from any class.

You can use as your app requires.

Answer (score 3):

Hold the score variable in the Main Activity:

```java
private int score = 0;
```

Write public functions to get and set the score in the activity:

```java
public void setScore(int score) {
    this.score = score;
}
    
public int getScore() {
    return this.score;
}
```

Now in the fragments, you can get and set score using:

```java
// getter
score = ((MainActivity) getContext()).getScore();
// setter
((MainActivity) getContext()).setScore(score);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the variable static in which your are storing your score  .

for eg : `public static int score=0`

by writing static it will have reference in memory and will be available until the
activity is running .

Answer (score 0):

Create a Java class and name it as DataHolder. Define score variable as a  global variable. Create getter & setter method as static. When you get score, set the values using set method. when you want to get score, use get method. Its simple java. Best thing is you can get and set score from any activity or any fragment using this method. Try below code.

DataHolder.java

```
    public class DataHolder {

    private static String Score="";

    public static void set_Score(String s){
        DataHolder.Score = s;
    }

    public static String get_Score(){
        return DataHolder.Score;
    }
}
```

To set score in DataHolder class, use below code from any fragment or activity.

```
String Score = ""; //get Score to this variable
DataHolder.set_Score(Score);
```

Answer (score 0):

try using **public static final** key word if your value is not going to be changed through out the app else use **public static** before the var type that will remain accessible in all files with out instantiation and value could be initialized at any instance .

**Example**:

```
public static int score;
public static final int score=5;
```

**Second way** is by using sharedprefrences , you can get help from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) .